# How to return a value from an object function when called inside a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, request

I would like to create a HTTP request inside a function using the request-json npm package.

Here is the code for the same:

```js
request = require('request-json')
client = request.createClient('http://localhost:5000')

function getData(){
    
    client.get('/currentdata', function(err, res, body){
        return console.log(body)
    })
    
}

getData()
```

This works fine on the console, but when I try `return body` instead of `return console.log(body)`, and change my function call statement as `var x = getData(); console.log(x);`, it gives me `undefined` as output.

I would like to know how to return a value from inside the client.get function to the main area, going through the getData() function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.